# Failed to connect to kafka cluster When running Kafka and Kafka-connect on different servers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I run Kafka and Kafka-connect on different servers (Let`s say serverA and serverB)

serverA for kafka connect

```sh
# vi /home/kafka/config/connect-distributed.properties

bootstrap.servers=serverB:9092
rest.host.name=localhost
rest.port=8083
```

serverB for kafka

```sh
# vi server.properties 

broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://serverA:9092
delete.topic.enable = true
```

But, when i run kafka connect on serverA, i got an error.

```
[2020-04-30 16:59:37,053] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:84)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:95)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1588233577048) timed out at 1588233577049 after 1 attempt(s)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:58)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1588233577048) timed out at 1588233577049 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

FYI, If i run kafka connect on kafka server(serverB), It worked. but, I want to run these on different server.

How can I connect kafka-connect to kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `server.properties` you have

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://serverA:9092
```

but Kafka connnects uses

```
bootstrap.servers=serverB:9092
```

instead of

```
bootstrap.servers=serverA:9092
```

Comment: I want to run kafka and kafka-connect on different servers.
so, I build
serverA: kafka-connect, no kafka
serverB: only kafka.

Couldn't I build servers like this?

Comment: I want to use serverA without kafka. only use kafka-connect. Is it impossible?

Comment: Were you able to run kafka connect and kafka on different servers ? I am getting same error while using different servers